# passing url parameters as a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently I have a simple parameter passing

*cshtml*

```
@Html.ActionLink("Ferrari", "Browse", new { product = Model.Name, brand = "Ferrari" })
@Html.ActionLink("Maserati", "Browse", new { product = Model.Name, brand = "Maserati" })
```

*controller*

```
public ActionResult Browse(string product, string brand)
{
    // Here a filter based on the passed parameters
}
```

It works ok but only one parameter as Ferrari, Maserati, etc.
I'd like by clicking the Ferrari and then Masserati pass both parameters.

I could retrieve parameter from viewBag and add new, then delete duplicates ... but this is not probably an elegant solution...

What is the best way to achieve this?

My aim is to select items as checkbox.

**Edit**

*cshtml*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Browse", "MyController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.CheckBox("brand", new { value = "Ferrari" })
    @Html.CheckBox("brand", new { value = "Masserati" })
}
```

*controller*

```
public ActionResult Browse(string product, string[] brand)
{
    // Here a filter based on the passed parameters
}
```

I would like to induce method of the controller after selecting checkbox. Currently, this is not happening.

Comment: You parameter will need to be `string[] brand` and each checkbox will need `name="brand"` (with `value="Ferrari"`, `value="Maserati"` etc and use a form with `FormMethod.Get`

Comment: Ok, I added checkboxes according to the advice. I added to them  `@using (Html.BeginForm("Browse", "MyController", FormMethod.Get)) {` , but after choosing does not invoke method of the controller. What could be the reason?

Comment: Edit you question with the code you have tried and we can help you.

Comment: You cant use `@Html.CheckBox()` (and you should never attempt to override the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods). Just generate the checkboxes manually - `<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Ferrari" />` and of course add a submit button

Comment: And do you really have a controller named `MyControllerController`?

Comment: Works perfectly. It would be wonderful if the method call by making when you select a car without submit button. You can achieve something like this?

Comment: Regarding the name of the controller - not :) I'm writing from the smartphone and such stupidity typed :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111683/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user3128303).